# Authenticate users with Microsoft without registering an app

Tags: node.js, authentication, azure-active-directory

I want to authenticate users to my nodejs app via Login with Microsoft but I don't want access to any of their AD data other than read access to email and first name.

I know I have authenticated to apps via my work MS account and that app has not been "registered" in my company's Azure env.  I have even used apps that do request access to my Calendar (Graph API) and I can grant it without that app being registered.

How does this work?  Is it possible to just use MS as my identity provider for authentication without my app being registered?

Answer (score 1):

In order to authenticate a user, a client ID is required.
This must come from a registered application.

There could be a situation in which another application is just using a client ID of another application (in case redirect URIs are able to match).
In the general case I would say that you must register an application.

Comment: Are there ways for the app to register itself then? I just granted MS Calendar access to an app (usemotion.com).  There's no way that app already had a registered app and a clientid with my company's azure environment.

Comment: Ah, that's a multi-tenant app! They register the app in their Azure AD, mark it as multi-tenant, and when you sign in and consent to the permissions required, an enterprise application (aka service principal) is created in your Azure AD for it.